# Using router push inside sweetalert onOpen function - Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using this library [vue-sweetalert2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sweetalert2). Purpose of the code, is to redirect to another path, when user clicks "OK" in sweetalert's modal window:

```
methods: {
  customMethod () {
    this.$swal({
      title: resp.data.displayText,
      type: 'success',
      onClose () {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'AnotherPage' })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

But it won't work, because i'm getting an error about `Cannot read property '$router' of undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, using arrow function:

```
onClose: () => {
  this.$router.push({ name: 'AnotherPage' })
}
```